# Separable Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> The question is: $$t^5\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + y^5 = 0$$

The next step says $\frac{1}{y^5}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{1}{t^5} = 0$ i understand this. However it then says:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(-\frac{1}{4 y^4} -\frac{1}{4t^4}) = 0$$ which I understand the bracket part is integrated it but what does the $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ mean?

And then from that how did it become $y(t)=(c-t^{-4})^{-1/4}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the ODE:

$$t^{5}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}+y^{5}=0$$

We can therefore rearrange this to give:

$$t^{5}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=-y^{5}$$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{t^{5}y^{5}}$, we get:

$$\frac{1}{y^{5}}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=-\frac{1}{t^{5}}$$

Multiplying both sides by $\mathrm{d}t$, we get:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^{5}}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^5}$$

Integrating, we get:

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^{5}}=-\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^{5}} \implies -\frac{1}{4y^{4}}=\frac{1}{4t^{4}}+C$$

Multiplying both sides by $-4$, we get:

$$\frac{1}{y^{4}}=-\frac{1}{t^{4}}+C$$

Taking the reciprocal of both sides we get:

$$y^{4}=\frac{1}{C-t^{-4}}$$

Taking the 4th root, we get:

$$y(t)=\pm\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{C-t^{-4}}}$$